# In SASS, how to avoid space before interpolation when creating a selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass, interpolation, css-sprites

### What I've already done

I use sprite images and have a SASS rule that goes like this to assign a bunch of properties (a mixin actually) to all these classes:

```
.success-16, .error-16, .warning-16, .info-16, 
.user-16, .plus-16, .logout-16, .star-16, .question-16, 
.document-16, .save-16, .cancel-16, .email-16, .search-16
{
    @include sprite(16, 'img/Sprites16.png');
    // This @include inserts a bunch of properties common to all classes
}
```

And then I have another `@include` with arguments to insert the `background-position` property calculated for each class. Something like:

```
.success-16
{
    @include spritePosition(16, 2, 1);
}

.error-16
{
    @include spritePosition(16, 3, 1);
}

// ... and so on.
```

This code outputs a CSS like this:

```
.success-16, .error-16, .warning-16, .info-16, 
.user-16, .plus-16, .logout-16, .star-16, .question-16, 
.document-16, .save-16, .cancel-16, .email-16, .search-16
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px;
    background: url(img/Sprites16.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    /* ...and more rules */
}

.success-16 { background-position: -16px 0px; }

.error-16 { background-position: -32px 0px; }
```

### What I want to do

Now, the new requirement is when any of these classes is applied to an `<img>` element I need to overwrite the `margin-right` property, so I thought of saving all my selectors in a string variable:

```
// This variable holds all my selectors
$All_selectors: '.success-16, .error-16, .warning-16, .info-16, 
.user-16, .plus-16, .logout-16, .star-16, .question-16, 
.document-16, .save-16, .cancel-16, .email-16, .search-16';
```

and then use interpolation to create the new rule referencing the parent selector:

```
img
{
    &#{$All_selectors}
    {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

This code produces the following CSS output:

```
img.success-16, img .error-16, img .warning-16, img .info-16, img .user-16, 
img .plus-16, img .logout-16, img .star-16, img .question-16, img .document-16, 
img .save-16, img .cancel-16, img .email-16, img .search-16
{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

This turns out to work, but only for the first selector in the variable string. **Notice how the interpolation adds a space between the `img` and the class name for the rest of the selectors**.

I have already tried to remove the spaces in the `$All_Selectors` string variable, but this does nothing, the spaces appear there anyway.

### The question

As you know, the space in between makes the rule to fail, as it is interpreted as the class being a descendant of the `img` element, and not part of it.

Does anyone has any idea how to avoid interpolation to add this extra space that messes up my code?. Thanks.

## --- UPDATE ---

### The solution

Thanks to [Russ Ferri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344543/russ-ferri) answer I came up with a solution using [placeholder selectors](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders):

```
img%iconsPH // %iconsPH is just a placeholder that will be replaced with the selectors that use the "@extend %iconsPH" instruction.
{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

The previous code outputs nothing, until I use it in an `@extend` instruction:

```
#{$All_selectors}
{
    @extend %iconsPH;
}
```

This code outputs what I was looking for:

```
img.success-16, img.error-16, img.warning-16, img.info-16, img.user-16, 
img.plus-16, img.logout-16, img.star-16, img.question-16, img.document-16, 
img.save-16, img.cancel-16, img.email-16, img.search-16
{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Everything works now. :)

### More info

Just in case you were wondering what my mixins do, here they are. My sprite image `$file` is a grid of icons, and I use rows and columns in it to calculate each image position. I use the same mixin for icon grids of a different size.

```
// 'sprite' mixin groups all the properties to be applied to a sprite class.
@mixin sprite($size, $file)
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    width: $size + px;
    height: $size + px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: $size * 2 + px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: url($file) no-repeat 0 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

// 'spritePosition' adds the background-position property with calculated values upon the icon size and the icon position within the sprite image.
@mixin spritePosition($size, $col, $row)
{
    background-position: -($size * ($col - 1)) + px + ' ' + -($size * ($row - 1)) + px;
}
```

I used [Mindscape Web Workbench VS extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a) to compile all my SCSS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for extending a base [placeholder selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders).

```
// Base rules for all sprites...
%sprite-16 {
    @include sprite(16, 'img/Sprites16.png');
}

img%sprite-16 {
    margin-right: 0;
}

// Rules for individual sprites...
.success-16 {
    @extend %sprite-16;
    @include spritePosition(16, 2, 1);
}

.error-16 {
    @extend %sprite-16;
    @include spritePosition(16, 3, 1);
}

// ...
```

[example](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7921627)

Comment: I never heard of these `placeholder selectors`. I'll give them a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: It worked! However, I used the string variable to generate all classes at once, instead of extending each one individually. I'll update my question with your solution. Thank you!